# Seeding files in ubuntu server ISO

Tags: iso, custom-distributions, debian-installer, custom-installer

I'm working with an ubuntu-server-install ISO. I've a `file.tar.gz` file that I want to have in the system after installation of ISO. Where should it be placed in the mounted ISO, so that it can be located in the target system when installation is complete?
I've tried placing it in the `/boot`, `/pool/extras/bundle` and after installation tried to `sudo find / -name file.tar.gz` to locate the file without luck.